# ggplot scale_size_manual function doesn't work

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to ggplot, and I'm not sure how to properly use scale_size_manual on groups of data. I tried to show the label at the right of graph, for example "0-200000", "800000+", but it does not show up on the graph.

```
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year1, imdb_rating)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = multi_language, size = imdb_votes1)) +
  scale_size(breaks = c(1,2,3,4),
             labels = c('0-200000','200000-400000','400000-800000','800000+'))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fpv37.png)

if i use scale_size, this is how it shows. If i change scale_size to scale_size_manual, it won't output anything and shows error "
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale"

the glimpse value of imdb_votes1 is
`glimpse(data$imdb_votes1) num [1:269] 7993 37573 24169 6725 22375 ...`

The data$imdb_votes1 is a continuous variable,so I'm not sure how to deal with it. Any help is appreciated, thank you so much

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neNeZ.png)
this is how i want it to be shown, except i change the label and name

Comment: But your code doesn’t use `scale_size_manual()`…. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I changed it to scale_size_manual and it shows "Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale"

Comment: Can you also paste your data into the question? For example if you run `dput(data)` and paste the output here, it would help people with answering what you need. It also doesn't look like your full code is there because clearly you have `geom_smooth` included in your plot but not your command.

Comment: `scale_size_manual` is a discrete scale, i.e. to use it you have to discretize your `imdb_votes1` variable using e.g. `cut` so that you have categories.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have updated my question, data$imdb_votes1 is a list of num. Could you be more specific on where i should i apply cut?